# Legend tag contain text aligned left in JQuery mobile?

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-fieldset

Does anybody have idea why `<legend>` tag is not centering in the JQuery mobile ? For example I tried following code.

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-theme="a">
                <legend>I would this site.<legend>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2-6" id="radio-choice-1-6" value="choice-1-6" />
                <label for="radio-choice-1-6">1</label>

                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2-6" id="radio-choice-2-6" value="choice-2-6" />
                <label for="radio-choice-2-6">2</label>

                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2-6" id="radio-choice-3-6" value="choice-3-6"  />
                <label for="radio-choice-3-6">3</label>

                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2-6" id="radio-choice-4-6" value="choice-4-6"  />
                <label for="radio-choice-4-6">4</label>

                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2-6" id="radio-choice-5-6" value="choice-5-6"  />
                <label for="radio-choice-5-6">5</label>
            </fieldset>
```

When I check on the mobile and simulators the `<legend>` tag hold text is aligned left even though I apply the style `text-align: center` for the `<legend>` tag. However if I put a longer text then it's works fine. eg:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-theme="a">
                <legend><p>If given the choice, I would rather spend time with my family than with friends or working.</p><legend>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2-8" id="radio-choice-1-8" value="choice-1-8" />
                <label for="radio-choice-1-8">1</label>

                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2-8" id="radio-choice-2-8" value="choice-2-8" />
                <label for="radio-choice-2-8">2</label>

                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2-8" id="radio-choice-3-8" value="choice-3-8"  />
                <label for="radio-choice-3-8">3</label>

                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2-8" id="radio-choice-4-8" value="choice-4-8"  />
                <label for="radio-choice-4-8">4</label>

                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2-8" id="radio-choice-5-8" value="choice-5-8"  />
                <label for="radio-choice-5-8">5</label>
            </fieldset>
```

Could any please shout with an answer ?

Comment: have your tried making the `legend` `display:block` explicitly, and that it's not floated? Same goes for the `fieldset` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because in your first example legend no longer exist after jQuery Mobile restyled the page.

Instead of legend tag like this:

```
<legend>I would this site.</legend>
```

New structure look like this:

```
<div class="ui-controlgroup-label" role="heading">I would this site.</div>
```

Or if you want a full look, your new HTML (after jQM restyling) looks like this:

```
<fieldset id="custom-fieldset" data-theme="a" data-type="horizontal" data-role="controlgroup" class="ui-corner-all ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-horizontal">
    <div class="ui-controlgroup-label" role="heading">I would this site.</div>
    <div class="ui-controlgroup-controls">
        <div class="ui-radio"><input type="radio" value="choice-1-6" id="radio-choice-1-6" name="radio-choice-2-6"><label for="radio-choice-1-6" data-corners="true" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-radio-off ui-corner-left ui-btn-up-c"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-corner-left"><span class="ui-btn-text">1</span></span></label></div>
        <div class="ui-radio"><input type="radio" value="choice-2-6" id="radio-choice-2-6" name="radio-choice-2-6"><label for="radio-choice-2-6" data-corners="true" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-radio-off ui-btn-up-c"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">2</span></span></label></div>
        <div class="ui-radio"><input type="radio" value="choice-3-6" id="radio-choice-3-6" name="radio-choice-2-6"><label for="radio-choice-3-6" data-corners="true" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-radio-off"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">3</span></span></label></div>
        <div class="ui-radio"><input type="radio" value="choice-4-6" id="radio-choice-4-6" name="radio-choice-2-6"><label for="radio-choice-4-6" data-corners="true" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-radio-off"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">4</span></span></label></div>
        <div class="ui-radio"><input type="radio" value="choice-5-6" id="radio-choice-5-6" name="radio-choice-2-6"><label for="radio-choice-5-6" data-corners="true" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-radio-off ui-corner-right ui-controlgroup-last"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-corner-right ui-controlgroup-last"><span class="ui-btn-text">5</span></span></label></div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Now you can use additional css to change this, like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/YBSDb/

```
#custom-fieldset .ui-controlgroup-label {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Please see the following to see different act of `<legend>` tag for single line text and double line text. http://www.apartmentslanka.com/ztest_calender/test_radio.html

Comment: Apologies about my Initial comment actually I've now deleted that. I was meant this `.survey_form fieldset .ui-controlgroup-label { text-align: center; }`

Comment: Sry I don't understand what do you want to say?

Comment: Can you pls check my link in mobile and you'll see <legend> tag hold text are aligned left but not the longer text.

Comment: What did I told you? When jQuery Mobile restyles the page legend is removed with this: <div class="ui-controlgroup-label" role="heading">I would this site.</div> so it will no longer work like legend. You need to manually change new css to make it work (also shown in my example)

Comment: Sorry mac, I Just confused and you're Right.

Answer (score 0):

To use  tag seems to work for JQM1.4.3:

```
<legend>
    <div style="text-align : center;">I would this site.</div>
</legend>
```